# how to execute jquery code(change the colour of text on hover) only when checkbox is clicked without submit

Tags: jquery, checkbox, hover

1. I have the below jquery code to change the colour of text on hovering.

   `$('.classA').hover(function() {
                               $(this).css("background-color", "#CEDEFF");
                           }, function() {
                               $(this).css("background-color", "#CEDEFF");
                           });`
2. I have the below checkbox.

I am trying to enable the hovering feature only when the click the checkbox by using the below code.  But the hovering feature is getting executed always nomatter I click the checkbox or not.

```
 $('#highLightTheViewed').click(function() {
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
//hovering code to change the colour
}
}
```

I can achieve this functionality by submitting the form onclick of checkbox and setting the sessiion variable and using it back in JSP. But I dont want to submit form since it has peformance issues.

```
if(${isHighLightTheViewed}){
//hivering code to change the colour.
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: Try this 
$('#highLightTheViewed').on("change",function(){
      if($(this).is(":checked")){
   //hovering code to change the color 
}
});

Comment: One question ..why you are showing the same background color while hovering in and out ?

Comment: I want to have item (which I hovered) remained with same colour even after I leave the item. I have this functionality working as expected. But only issue is enabling this hovering feature only when checkbox is clicked.

Comment: By click what do you mean ? it should be checked ?? And did you try my code I posted ?

Comment: I don't know why you are showing the same colour . As you have written    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
//hovering code to change the colour
} 
But you are not changing the colour . So why you have written "hovering code to change the colour " ?

Comment: By click ..meaning..by checking the checkbox. sorry for confusion. Yes, I tried the code but no luck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I caught you . Your jquery hover event is executing everytime because that "hover" event once gets binded will not be unbind itself unless you unbind it . What you have to do is , you have to unbind the "hover" event . Try my edited fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Tushar490/qeuoo4wc/3/

Now the code should be like this for checkbox :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#highLightTheViewed').on("change", function () {
    if ($('#highLightTheViewed').is(":checked")) {
        $('.classA').hover(function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#CEDEFF");
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("background-color", "#CEDEFF");
        });
    } else {

        if (typeof $('.classA').attr('style') !== typeof undefined && $('.classA').attr('style') !== false) {
            $('.classA').removeAttr('style');
            $('.classA').unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
        }
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: The problem is basically my jquery code gets executes always even if I  put condition(only when checkbox is checked).

Comment: Your fiddle looks perfect Tushar. Thanks. It seems somewhere I am doing a mistake.

Comment: I caught you .Try my updated fiddle in the answer .This will definetly works for you .You have not unbinded the hover event that's why once it gets binded , your jquery hovering function being executed everytime . So , you need to unbind the "hover" event .

Comment: @TusharRaj still your answer is wrong. I guess you misunderstand the requirements.

Comment: get your eyes checked @SandipVora I have unbinded the hover event . The requirements was misunderstood by you and you just wrote according to yourself what suits you best . This is not the way .

Comment: @TusharRaj it seems you misunderstood requirements. And your answer is already rejected. ;)

Comment: Pleasure @KishorePaparthi :) Happy Coding :)

Comment: @DarshakShekhda  Thanks for opening my eyes :D

Answer (score 1):

First thing is that you have mentioned in question that you want to change text color on hover but you have used "background-color" instead "color". So, you need to use "color" there.

Here is the code. I have used color property.

```
function onHoverIn(){
    $(this).css('color', "#f00");
}

function onHoverOut(){
    $(this).css('color', "#00f");
}

$('#highLightTheViewed').change(function(){

    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        $('.classA').bind('mouseover', onHoverIn);
        $('.classA').bind('mouseout', onHoverOut);
    }   
    else{
        $('.classA').unbind('mouseover');
        $('.classA').unbind('mouseout');
    }
});
```

Comment: Use hoverin and hoverout color which ever you want. You can change css property as well.. whichever you want.

Comment: Try this out this will work for sure. Try out this link http://jsfiddle.net/smvora_4u/mg8s373o/

Comment: @Kishore Paparthi This code is absolutely okay .But you want "hover feature .Isn't it ? I have my code for your hover event . Please check that out .

Comment: @Tusahr Raj, indirectly this is hover feature. The problem in your code is that you bind hover feature if check box is checked. Once checkbox checked hover feature is bound but if you uncheck checkbox again you did not unbind hover feature.

Comment: you haven't saw my code .Check in else condition . I have unbinded the hover event . You misunderstood the requirements and what you wrote is absolutely nonsense .

Comment: But this nonsense works for the questioner. I have gone to your sample in fiddle. In your code its a one way code. Once you hover over text effects applied what about hover out? Hovering effect itself includes hoverin and hoverout both. It should be same as before on hoverout.

Comment: @Sandip, Thanks for trying to help me. But I should say, Tushar code worked for me. The trick is with "unbind" method. Tushar got it right.

Comment: Better luck next time @SandipVora

Comment: Good job @TusharRaj. Sorry for misunderstanding Kishore Paparthi.